# Open Externally Locked Neo4j Store

Tags: neo4j, centos, locking, file-locking

I am currently unable to start a neo4j instance on a server where it was previously working. Neo4j produces an error saying one of the files is externally locked. From reading answers to similar questions I know this usually means another instance is currently using the store.

I have used lsof to look for any open files with 'neo' in their name but there are no open files.

I have used ps to look for any process with 'neo' or 'java' it it's name but no luck with that either.

I am not sure where to go from here to get neo4j working again. How do I figure out why this file is locked?

```
[site@x neo4j]$ neo4jstart-234.sh
[site@x neo4j]$ WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
2017-07-20 10:37:51.073-0400 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2017-07-20 10:37:51.074-0400 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@79b877d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@79b877d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@79b877d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:235)
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@79b877d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:195)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /scratch/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.3.4/data/graph.db
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@14c7f72f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to open store file: /scratch/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.3.4/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:161)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.initialise(CommonAbstractStore.java:102)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.initialize(NeoStores.java:429)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores$StoreType$1.open(NeoStores.java:85)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores$StoreType$1.open(NeoStores.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.openStore(NeoStores.java:422)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.getOrCreateStore(NeoStores.java:467)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:365)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:174)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:138)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildNeoStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:661)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:535)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: Externally locked: /scratch/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.3.4/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db.labels
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.acquireLock(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:209)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:160)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:64)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:95)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:357)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:140)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Is /scratch on a local filesystem or on a remote one ?

Comment: @TomGeudens it is a local directory. Also I've tried restarting the server to see if it was a defunct proccess, but that didn't help